# MLR - calculating feature importance for bagged, boosted trees (XGBoost)

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost, feature-selection, mlr

Good morning,

I have a question about calculating feature importance for **bagged** and **boosted** regression tree models with MLR package in R. I am using XGBOOST to make predictions and i'm using bagging to estimate prediction uncertainty. My data set is relatively large; approximately 10k features and observations. The predictions work perfectly (see code below), but I can't seem to calculate feature importance (the last line in the code below). The importance function crashes with no errors... and freezes the R session. I saw some related python code, where people seem to calculate the importance for each of the bagged models [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333573/feature-importances-bagging-scikit-learn) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519113/feature-importance-in-logistic-regression-with-bagging-classifier). I haven't been able to get that to work properly in R either. Specifically, i'm not sure how to access individual models within the objected produced by MLR (**mb** object in the code below). In python, this seems to be trivial. In R, i can't seem to extract `mb$learner.model`, which seems logically closest to what i need. So i'm wondering if anyone had any experience with this issues?

Please see the code below

```
learn1 <- makeRegrTask(data = train.all , target= "resp", weights = weights1)
lrn.xgb <- makeLearner("regr.xgboost", predict.type = "response")
lrn.xgb$par.vals <- list( objective="reg:squarederror", eval_metric="error", nrounds=300, gamma=0, booster="gbtree", max.depth=6)

lrn.xgb.bag = makeBaggingWrapper(lrn.xgb, bw.iters = 50, bw.replace = TRUE,  bw.size = 0.85, bw.feats = 1)
lrn.xgb.bag <- setPredictType(lrn.xgb.bag, predict.type="se")
mb = mlr::train(lrn.xgb.bag, learn1)

fimp1 <- getFeatureImportance(mb)
```

Comment: `getFeatureImportance()` takes a wrapped model so `mb` should be fine here. Also see `?mlr::getLearnerModel()`. Have a look at the [vignettes](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/) also.

Comment: @pat-s Thank you. I'm getting some interesting errors with these option. `mlr::getFeatureImportance(mb)` gives me `Error in xgboost::xgb.importance(feature_names = .model$features, model = mod : model: must be an object of class xgb.Booster`. However, i can extract individual model `mb1 <- getLearnerModel(mb, more.unwrap = T)`, try to get importance for a single model `mlr::getFeatureImportance(mb1[[1]])` and get 
`Error: Assertion on 'object' failed: Must inherit from class 'WrappedModel', but has class 'xgb.Booster'`. This looks to me like a class issue?

Comment: @pat-s was partly wrong. `getFeatureImportance()` takes a `WrappedModel` but the model created by a *BaggingWrapper* is a `HomogeneousEnsembleModel`, for which *mlr* does not offer an own method. So you have to aggregate the feature importance values manually. However, it won't work if each model is just trained on one feature (`bw.feats = 1`) like in your example.

Comment: @jakob-r Thanks. The `bw.feats=1` refers to "Percentage size of randomly selected features in bags", so each model has many features. But thanks for the clarification. However, if i understand you correctly, i can manually create a ensemble with 50 different models (same learner but different names) and then the `getFeatureImportance()` should work on the ensemble?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. `bw.feats = 1` equals 100% of the features which is a sensible decision. I posted an answer that should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `bw.feats = 1` it might be feasible to average the feature importance values.
Basically you just have to apply over all single models that are stored in the `HomogeneousEnsembleModel`. Some extra care is necessary because the order of the features gets mixed up because of the sampling - although we set it to 100%.

```r
library(mlr)
data = data.frame(x1 = runif(100), x2 = runif(100), x3 = runif(100))
data$y = with(data, x1 + 2 * x2 + 0.1 * x3 + rnorm(100))
task = makeRegrTask(data = data, target = "y")
lrn.xgb = makeLearner("regr.xgboost", predict.type = "response")
lrn.xgb$par.vals = list( objective="reg:squarederror", eval_metric="error", nrounds=50, gamma=0, booster="gbtree", max.depth=6)

lrn.xgb.bag = makeBaggingWrapper(lrn.xgb, bw.iters = 10, bw.replace = TRUE,  bw.size = 0.85, bw.feats = 1)
lrn.xgb.bag = setPredictType(lrn.xgb.bag, predict.type="se")
mb = mlr::train(lrn.xgb.bag, task)
fimps = lapply(mb$learner.model$next.model, function(x) getFeatureImportance(x)$res)
fimp = fimps[[1]]
# we have to take extra care because the results are not ordered
for (i in 2:length(fimps)) {
  fimp = merge(fimp, fimps[[i]], by = "variable")
}
rowMeans(fimp[,-1]) # only makes sense with bw.feats = 1
# [1] 0.2787052 0.4853880 0.2359068
```